# Not able to run the Dynamic web project in jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat7

I am using the **Eclipse** and **Apache Tomcat 7** for running a Dynamic web project MyOnlineShopping(Java, jsp and servlet).  When I run the project, It is showing the error as Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.

Multiple Contexts have a path of "`/myonlineShopping`". 
Anyone help me to figure out what is the error and solution is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In Eclipse Eclipse**

1. Open `Project Explorer`
2. Go inside `Servers -> Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost`
3. Open `server.xml`
4. Search for tag
5. There should be multiple definitions for the path of your project.
   Remove the multiple one

Comment: Now it is showing the another error.as Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.Error copying file shopscript.js: Access is denied